# Expo APK file doesn't work, I open it, the moment it closes?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an Expo React Native project. After building the project, i install it on the phone. But when i try to open the APK file i installed, the application closes immediately.

My eas.json:

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I tried to build but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. react-native-safe-area-context and react-native-screens packages need to be downloaded

Comment: npx expo install react-native-screens , that's how you installed it?